# Static factory method in abstract class

Tags: typescript, oop

I am building a class system in Typescript. There is a main abstract class `Component`, that has a static method `create()`. This method will be called on children to build a particular instance

```
abstract class Component {
    static build() {
       // some additional logic here, for example, cache to reuse instances
       return new this();
    }
}

class Button extends Component { }
class Input extends Component {}

Button.build(); // returns Button instance
Input.build(); // returns Input instance
```

[Same code in TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Component%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20build()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Button%20extends%20Component%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Input%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AButton.build()%3B%0D%0AInput.build()%3B)

This approach works well in Javascript, but Typescript reports an error at the line `new this()`, saying "Cannot create an instance of an abstract class."

How can I explain typescript that method will be called on derived instances, but not on the main abstract class directly? Maybe there are other ways to implement the API that I needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` is `typeof Component`, and since `Component` is abstract class, `new this` is inadmissible. Even if `Component` wasn't abstract, `Button.build()` return type wouldn't be properly handled in child classes.

It requires some type hinting, via [generic method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
abstract class Component {
    static build<T = Component>(this: { new(): T }) {
       return new this();
    }
}

class Button extends Component { }

const button = Button.build<Button>(); // button: Button
```

Comment: Can you explain or give reference on generics in Typescript with real example?

Comment: You don't need the type parameter when you call the function. `const button = Button.build(); ` this has the same effect

Comment: @Karabah I added a link.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir What do you mean? To my knowledge, typing system can't identify `new this` as `Button` without a hint.

Comment: Great this works, thank you! I did not know that it is possible to declare the type of `this` via the argument. @estus where can I read more about this feature?

Comment: @estus try it out, it worked for me this morning on 2.8 without specifying the type parameter. Might have been sleepy but I'm pretty sure :-)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm using 2.7, so it would be great to know if there were recent improvements.

Comment: @just-boris See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters . The feature's very useful indeed.

Comment: @estus It works on 2.7 as well just tested it, `this` will be inferred based on the target. You can write `const button = Button.build(); ` and `button` will be of type `Button`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir What `static build` should look like in this case? In the OP, there's a link to the playground, you can see that `new this` isn't typed properly, and `Button.build()` returns `any`.

Comment: You just need to remove the explicit argument from the call, not the definition. Working sample: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Component%20%7B%0D%0A%09static%20build%3CT%20%3D%20Component%3E(this%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20T%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%20%20%20return%20new%20this()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Button%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0D%0A%09test%3A%20number%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20button%20%3D%20Button.build()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(button.test)%3B%0D%0A

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir That's quite surprising. I would expect it to be `Component`, considering that it was specified as `T = Component`. Do you have an explanation for that?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to call factory method without using generics. Also to use type safety in factory classes, some type casting is necessary.

Below is two example classes, one with abstract class and one with non-abstract class:

```
/* eslint-disable prefer-destructuring, max-classes-per-file */

type Class<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class BaseComponent {
  static a = 1;

  static build<C extends typeof BaseComponent = typeof BaseComponent>(this: C): InstanceType<C> {
    const a = this.a;
    return new this() as InstanceType<C>;
  }
}

abstract class AbstractComponent {
  static a = 1;

  static build<T extends AbstractComponent = AbstractComponent>(this: Class<T>): T {
    const This = (this as any) as typeof AbstractComponent; AbstractComponent; // To be able to use type safety
    const a = This.a;
    return new this();
  }
}

class AButton extends AbstractComponent {
  x = 0;
}

class BButton extends BaseComponent {
  x = 0;
}

const aButton = AButton.build();
const bButton = BButton.build();

console.log(aButton.x, bButton.x);
```